# Did Romans collect notes/minutes/protocols of Senate meetings? Ditto Greeks?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece

Did Romans have official note-takers of important meetings, such as Senate debates? If so, did any of them survive?

Similarly for Greeks. Plato's "Apology" is the closest thing to minutes that I've read; however, it wasn't written contemporarily to the meeting.

I wonder whether such minutes, recorded at the time of important assemblies, exist...

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: For the Romans, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acta_Senatus

Comment: @CarlosMartin  That would make a good answer.

Comment: It's very improbable that these note-takers have survived; they lived two thousand years ago, after all.

Comment: @KrišjānisLiepiņš, in the hearts and souls of the grateful historians, they may.